# Como trocar de página após inserir objeto no banco de dados?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Eu criei um página JSF com um formulário de cliente, após salvar cliente apertando no botão cadastrar. O objeto persisti no BD, e consequentemente eu gostaria que trocasse de pagina indo para a `index.xhtml` ou limpar os campos do formulário para continuar cadastrando clientes.

#### cadastroCliente.xhtml

```
<form>
    <!-- inputTexts referentes ao cliente. Aqui-->
    <p:commandButton value="Cadastrar" id="cadastrar" ajax="false" 
        style="margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom:7px;"
        action="#{clienteBean.inserir}">
    </p:commandButton>
</form>
```

#### clienteBean.java

```
public void inserir(){
    dataCadastro = new Date();
    Session session = DAOHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    try{
        session.beginTransaction();
        if(!isCpfValido(session)){
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("cpfmessage", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,"CPF já cadastrado", "este CPF já esta sendo utilizado!"));
        }else{
            Cliente cliente = this;
            session.save(cliente);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            cliente = new Cliente();
        }
    }catch(RuntimeException e){
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }finally{
        if(session.isConnected()){
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Estou iniciando agora com JSF portando se meu código estiver errado fico grato em ajuda para corrigir, mas esse código está funcionando, persistindo no banco corretamente.

O problema é como abrir outra página ou limpar os `inputtext` do formulário após clicar no botão cadastrar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu sugiro que você dê uma lida no [tutorial oficial sobre JSF](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-intro.htm#BNAPH) do Java EE, em especial no capítulo sobre o [Modelo de Navegação](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-intro005.htm#BNAQL) do JSF. Esse é um assunto razoavelmente complexo.

Para te dar uma resposta pragmática, seu método deve retornar uma `String` com o *outcome* da ação.

```
public String inserir() {
   // ...
   return "index";
}
```

Nesse caso há navegação **implícita** da *view* `cadastroCliente` para a *view* `index`.

Também é possível declarar regras de navegação **explícitas** em arquivos de configuração como `faces-config.xml`:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/cadastroCliente.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Nesse caso, toda vez que a *outcome* de uma ação em `cadastroCliente.xhtml` for `success` será apresentada a *view* `index`.

Comment: Anthony eu utilizo faces-config.xml. Implementei o return "index", funcionou em partes, pois recarregou a página para o index, mas a url no navegador não mudou, continuou com a url de cadastro de cliente. Aparentemene só inflou o html, mas não houve redirecionamento de página

Comment: Obrigado pela documentação.

Comment: Juarez, mais um dos muitos detalhes do modelo de navegação. Por *default* o JSF faz *forward*, para fazer *redirect* você precisa declarar isso explicitamente. Com navegação implícita use `index?faces-redirect=true`, com navegação explícita use `<redirect/>`.

Comment: Obrigado Anthony, problema resolvido, usei <redirect/> no faces-config.xml e retornando o outcome da pagina no método inserir, e com essa mesma solução posso fazer um redirect para mesma pagina e os campos ficam limpos. Obrigado! é osso esse JSF, vou me matar na documentação, grato!